# mysql / mariaDB on Raspberry 4 (Buster) troubles with connections / rights; Error by phpMyadmin; no connection by MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql

my project is, a weatherstation with 7 sensors (Arduino MEGA) sent data to the Server "RASPI02" by a php-script

in the access-protokoll I can see the proper messages with  ... enter image description here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Micv6.jpg)"http/1.1" 200 2075 response,
this side should be ok

but something in this sketch must be wrong, because the data will not be added in the database
the database is ready and data are insert by doing directly by the mariaDB-monitor (screenshot1)

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","WEATHER");
  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Error connecting to MySQL db: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

   $tempin = $_GET["tempin"];
   $temp = $_GET["temp"];
   $dew = $_GET["dew"];
   $heat = $_GET["heat"];
   $speed = $_GET["wspd"];
   $gust = $_GET["gust"];
   $speedavg = $_GET["wspdavg"];
   $wdir = $_GET["wdir"];
   $wdiravg = $_GET["wdiravg"];
   $h = $_GET["hum"];
   $p = $_GET["pressure"];
   $rain = $_GET["rain"];
   $rainrate = $_GET["rainrate"];
   $rad = $_GET["rad"];
   $uvi = $_GET["uvi"];



   if($tempin== "" || $temp=="" || $p=="" || $h=="" || $tempin== 0 || $temp==0 || $p==0 || $h==0 || $tempin< -40 || $temp< -40 || $tempin>60 || $temp>60 || $p>1050 || $p<950 || $h==0.01 || $h==0.02 || $h==0.03 || $h>99)
   {
     echo 'We cannot save bad values to DB!';
   }
   else 
   {
     $ins = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `TEMP_db` (`tempin`) (`temp`) (`dew`) (`heat`) (`hum`) VALUES ('".$tempin."')('".$temp."')(\'b4".$dew."`)(\'b4".$heat."`)('".$h."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
     $ins1 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ``WIND_db`(`wspd`)(`gust`)(`wspdavg`)(`wdir`)(`wdiravg`) VALUES (\'b4".$speed."`)(\'b4".$gust."`)(\'b4".$speedavg."`)(\'b4".$wdir."`)(\'b4".$wdiavg."`)") or die (mysqli_error($con));
     $ins2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Pressure_db` (`pressure`) VALUES ('".$p."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
     $ins3 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `RAIN_db` (`rain`) (`rainrate`) VALUES ('".$rain."')('".$rainrate."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
     $ins4 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Solar_db` (`uvi`)(`rad`) VALUES ('".$uvi."')('".$rad."')") or die (mysqli_error($con));
     echo 'Datas saved succesfully!';
   } 

?>
```

when I start the MySQL Workbench I get the ERROR message, can't connect to the server?

in phpMyAdmin I can define users, can see the tables with the data, but when I opened it give a error-message but the entries are available (2 screenshot phpMA1 and phpMA2)

the are 3 problems

1-  sketch "data-get.php" $ins, $ins1 - 4 ... INSERT INTO ...
2-  MySQL Workbench, connecting problem
3-  phpMA error-message

I'm looking forward to get on this way further informations, because I have had study so may docs without to find a solution

many thanks in advance

Max Müller

sorry, I'm not able to put more screenshots!?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koU3Q.jpg)

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Answer (score 0):

in Line 10 to 24 it will giva a php notice: "undefined index: "
and as line 28 (echo) 'we can not... '

when I'm looking in the Apache2 access.log all data are correct

I can not understand the issue "undefined index"!